# Can I debug directly on an iPhone-5 (armv7s) iOS App built for only armv6 and armv7?

Tags: iphone, ios, debugging, build

Our iOS app relies on a commercial third-party static-lib currently only available for armv6+armv7. For this reason, I can't build our app for armv7s. Only armv6+armv7+simulator.

Our builds are deployed for and run on the iPhone-5 without a problem - it runs armv7 code.

However, I cannot find a way to debug directly on the iPhone 5. When I connect the iPhone-5 and try to build for debugging, I get linker errors like this:

```
"No architectures to compile for (ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES, active arch=armv7s, VALID_ARCHS=armv7)."
```

Initially,I thought that maybe my "Build only active architecture" setting for debug configuration caused Xcode not to try to build for armv7 when the iPhone-5 (armv7s) was connected.

But when I set this to "NO" (have Xcode build for ALL SUPPORTED ARCHITECTURES all the time) I get a whole other bunch of build errors (excerpt below --- we have many targets and each emits similar errors).

```
=== BUILD NATIVE TARGET ASPCommon OF PROJECT ASPCommon WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
Check dependencies
No architectures to compile for (ARCHS=i386, VALID_ARCHS=armv7).

** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
    Check dependencies
(1 failure)
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 65
```

This target has NO dependencies, it only builds against iOS SDK frameworks, and builds fine when any device other than iPad 4/iPhone 5 is connected.

Finally my question: Is it at all possible to directly debug armv7 code on armv7s device? If it is possible, when Am I doing wrong in my build settings to break this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No. I believe what you are attempting to do just isn't possible! The third party static lib needs to be rebuilt for armv7s. Keep hounding them until they update their library.

Comment: Hi, I forgot I posted this question… My answer to myself is -- Yes. It is possible. The problem is not in the libraries or in my code, but rather in an iOS Xcode Template I was using to create iOS "Framework" targets.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I forgot I posted this question…

Eventually I was able to debug on all iOS devices, as the source of the problem was neither in the armv7-only library, or my project/target settings.

The problem was in an iOS Xcode Template I was using to create iOS "Framework" targets. (an old version of [iOS Universal framework from Karl Stenerud](https://github.com/kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework)).

Our code-base is big, and many of its main blocks serve MacOS and iOS versions of the application, plus we want to encapsulate these main blocks as "SDK"s, including library, header, resources and documentation. So --- we've been using Framework targets for this. Since there's no internal "Framework" target template for iOS - we used a 3rd-party template.

This template users build-scripts, that had a bug, that omitted platforms from the build in certain situation, hence causing our build errors, and inability to debug.

Last word --- an update of the template removed the issue.